# RecycleView: how to go to a row without scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-recyclerview

If the recyclerview has a list of items and I want to go to a specific row immediately when user enters the UI, so I don't want the user to see it scroll to reach that row. Is it achievable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `scrollToPositionWithOffset (int position, int offset)`

> Scroll to the specified adapter position with the given offset from
>   resolved layout start.
>
> See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int))

**Example:**

```
//Scroll to item position 2 with offset 0
RECYCLERVIEW_LAYOUT_MANAGER.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 0);
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is impossible.

`RecyclerView#scrollToPosition` causes sort of animation because it does not know the height of all rows initially. Not all items are loaded immediatly but one by one as you scroll down the list.

Answer (score 0):

I use ListView and I solved the issue by calling setSelection(position)